# Push array to uppercase

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.myUcase=function()
{
    for (i=0;i<this.length;i++)
    {
        this[i]=this[i].toUpperCase();
    }
}

var fruits=["banana","sermnb","kiwi"];

function myFunction()
{
    fruits.push("hakki").myUcase();
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=fruits;
}
```

I want to uppercase the last array that is pushed. The above code doesn't work.

Comment: *"Want to uppercase the last array that is pushed."* Array, or array *entry*?

Comment: You've posted example input, but no example output. How should your array look after your code has run correctly?

Comment: Is this the whole code? because i isn't defined.

Comment: @user2422324 The `for` initializes `i` as a global variable. (You are correct that it should be `for( var i = 0; ...`)

Comment: @Juhana: `for (var i = ...` is misleading (in the current JavaScript).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not seeing it, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Juhana: [`var` is not block-scoped in JavaScript.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) (`let` will be, in ES6.) For a nice short function like that, it doesn't really matter though.

Comment: Yeah, ok, but since the for loop is the only thing in the function it shouldn't make any difference. (Although oops, it should be `var i=0`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
fruits.push("hakki").myUcase();
```

...calls `push` on the array, and then tries to call `myUcase` on the return value of `push`. But the return value of `push` is a number (the new length of the array), not a reference to the array.

It's unclear what you're trying to do, but you can make the string upper case before pushing it:

```
fruits.push("hakki".toUpperCase()); // I assume the string is actually in a variable.
```

...or just call `myUcase` later, when you're done pushing:

```
fruits.myUcase();
x.innerHTML=fruits;
```

---

Side note: It doesn't look like you're declaring `i` anywhere in your `myUcase` function. That means you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare it:

```
Array.prototype.myUcase = function() {
    var i; // <=== Declaration
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
fruits.push("hakki");
fruits.myUcase();
```

as `push` returns the length of the array after the item has been added.

As an aside, it's probably not a good idea to start modifying the prototype of native objects unless you know what you're doing. It's possible to achieve the same result in other ways:

```
fruits = fruits.map(function(str){
    return str.toUpperCase();
    });
```

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary loops through the array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd interpreted the objective as uppercasing each item in the array buy maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Right, but the OP's `myUCase` function goes through the whole array every time you call it. So calling it in the loop pushing the items is overkill.

Comment: Also, `fruits = fruits.map(String.toUpperCase);` doesn't work, for two different reasons: 1. The `String` function doesn't have a `toUpperCase` function, and 2. If you meant `String.prototype.toUpperCase`, it expects to act on `this`, not an argument.

Comment: Argh, I checked that in Firefox's console and it worked fine, but I didn't remember that this is non-standard. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`push` returns the length of the updated array. You cannot call `myUcase` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the "Last" entry in "UCase" then:

```
<script>
    Array.prototype.myUcase=function()
    {
    //for (i=0;i<this.length;i++)
   // {
    //this[i]=this[i].toUpperCase();
   // }
this[this.length-1]=this[this.length-1].toUpperCase();
    }

    var fruits=["banana","sermnb","kiwi"];

    function myFunction()
    {
    fruits.push("hakki");
    fruits.myUcase();
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=fruits;
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative consistent with your current approach.

```
Array.prototype.pushUpperCase = function(s) {
    this.push(s.toUpperCase());
};
```

and your invocation would be...

```
fruits.pushUpperCase("hakki");
```

Whether you want, need or should be adding string manipulators to your containers is another question.